# Responsive twitter height

Tags: html, css, twitter

I'm attempting to make the twitter embed widget responsive, to do this I need to make the height a percentage. As it stands I am using the default twitter embed from [here](https://twitter.com/settings/widgets)

That says I can set the height in advanced customization, however that is only for pixels.

Here is my code;

HTML:

```
        <div id="body-twitterFeed">
            <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/ARavinMadMonkey" data-widget-id="347000705833398272" height="700" data-chrome="noscrollbar transparent" border-color="#DBDBDB">Tweets by @ARavinMadMonkey</a>
            <script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+"://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>               
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
#body-twitterFeed{
height: 80%;
padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
overflow: hide;
```

}

I attempted to use overflow:hide; to hide anything outside of the body-twitterFeed div, but it just simply doesn't work.

If anyone could help me work out a way to make the height of the twitter feed responsive, it would help a lot!

Thanks in advance.
PS. I am not using bootstrap or anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the height of the class .twitterTimeline.

Theoretically this should be easy: just set it as a proportion of the window height (e.g., 40vh).  Trouble is that mobile Safari has trouble rendering vh properly.

Instead, I think you need to use media queries to set the height, as in the following example:

```
@media screen and (max-height: 30rem) {
    .twitter-timeline {
        height: 15rem;
    }
}
@media screen and (min-height: 30rem) {
    .twitter-timeline {
        height: 30rem;
    }
}
```

If you want to see more about media queries and what all they can do, [try reading this](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/).

Comment: I tried using this code, however the problem persists. The timeline still overflows into other divs, or even divs that aren't even there!
This is the problem I am trying to solve: http://prntscr.com/44rvgi
If you can think of any way to solve it please let me know!
(The grey bar going through the timeline is supposed to be the footer)

Comment: @user3858871 That's weird.  In [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/JqfT3/), it seems to show your desired behavior.

Could you post more of your code in a jsFiddle?  I wonder if it's something else that's causing your behavior; not sure what's going on.

Comment: Hm, very strange, it does work in jsFiddle but not for me.
Well here is the source on GitHub https://github.com/Crystic/CrysticSite
Thanks for the help by the way.

Comment: I pasted most of your source [here](http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/p4xx3/), and it still seems to work.  I'd rec the following: (1) First, are you using Chrome dev tools or the equivalent in another browser?  Find your .twitter-timeline element and see if the size is being set properly.  (2) Try removing/commenting out large swathes of your code and adding them back bit by bit.  This'll help you see what part of your code is causing it to behave in this fashion.  Keep me updated on your progress. If (1) and (2) don't work and you want me to take another glance, try uploading to BitBalloon.

Comment: try height: 30rem !important;